# Localization of $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ at $S=\begin{Bmatrix}b^n : n\in \mathbb{N}\end{Bmatrix}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, localization

> Could I say that $\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}\right)_{b}$, namely the localization at $S=\begin{Bmatrix}b^n : n\in \mathbb{N}\end{Bmatrix}$ when $(b,p)=1$, is equal to $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ because we have that 
>   $$\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}\right)_{b}\cong\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{ b}$$ 
>   and there we have (taking $r=\max(n,k)$)
>   $$ \bar{a}\otimes\frac{c}{b^n}= \bar{a}\otimes\frac{c}{b^n}\cdot 1=\bar{a}\otimes\frac{c}{b^n}\cdot(sb^r+tp^r)=\bar{a}\otimes csb^{r-n}+p^r\bar{a}\otimes \frac{ct}{b^n}=(csb^{r-n})\bar{a}\otimes 1 \ \ ?$$

I know that it is not a rigorous proof, but what I would like to say is that we can write every element of $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{b}$ as an element of $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: In fact, you localize at an invertible element in $\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z$, so get nothing new.

Answer (score 1):

I would make it a little simpler, starting from a *Bézout relation* between $b$ and $p^k$, $\;ub+vp^k=1$. There results that for any $n$, $u^n$ is the inverse of $b^n$ modulo $p^k$. So an element in $\bigl(\mathbf Z/p^k\mathbf Z)_b$ can be written as 
$$\frac{\bar a}{b^n}=\frac{u^n\bar a}{u^nb^n}=\frac{u^n\bar a}1.$$

Comment: Is this substantially the same thing i made above (but honestly in a more complicated way)?

Comment: Yes. There remains some details  to check, naturally. The main difference is I don't use a Bézout's relation for each power of $b$. Now the really short way, without computation, would to say that, since $b$ and its powers are already invertible in $\mathbf Z/p^k\mathbf Z$, it results from the universal property of rings (and modules) of fractions.

Comment: Could you remember me this universal property for modules? I know it for rings but I cannot rearrange it for modules.

Comment: The endomorphism of multiplication by an element of $S$ (the multiplicative subset) has to become bijective.

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks like to be a very weak condition :)